# Taking selected groups in regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to implement a regex which takes the string `3oranges` as one group and does not take more than 1 match for this string. I also want to give the string `3oranges2apples4bananas` and this should give 3 different groups accordingly.

I have tried creating a regex which gets the matches the way I want, but doesnt give only one group as a match. It gives 2 for each match : `3oranges` gives `oranges` and `3oranges` as matches.

Here is the regex I wrote. I am writing it this way because I want to restrict the order in which the data is given and also want to make sure I get a limited number of digits to process later on.

```
^(\d{1,4}(orange)){0,1}(\d{1,4}(apple)){0,1}(\d{1,4}(banana)){0,1}$
```

Like I said earlier, I want to get only a single group for desired match.

```
INPUT: 
3oranges2apples4bananas

OUTPUT: Matches found
3oranges
oranges
2apples
apples
4bananas
bananas

DESIRED OUTPUT:
3oranges
2apples
4bananas
```

Is what I am asking for possible, and if yes, how can I achieve this?

EDIT 1: 
I didnt realize the importance of the follow up question I had to this question, but I wont waste any time.
I also want to consider it as `oranges` if the text is `o`, `orange` or `oranges`
Something like this:

```
^(\d{1,4}(oranges|orange|o)){0,1}(\d{1,4}(apples|apple|a)){0,1}(\d{1,4}(bananas|banana|b)){0,1}$
```

Comment: Side note: `{0,1}` is equal to `?`

Comment: You mean you don’t want to put the things you’ve put in groups in groups, like `(orange)` → `orange`, `(apple)` → `apple`?

Comment: Try `^(\d{1,4}oranges?)?(\d{1,4}apples?)?(\d{1,4}bananas?)?$`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yep, that works, but I have a follow up question which was equally important. Please check the edit.

Comment: `(oranges|orange|o)` → `(?:oranges|orange|o)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
var s = "3oranges2apples4bananas";
var ms = Regex.Match(s, @"^(\d{1,4}o(?:ranges?)?)?(\d{1,4}a(?:pples?)?)?(\d{1,4}b(?:ananas?)?)?$");
var results = ms.Groups.Cast<Group>().Select(y => y.Value).Skip(1);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results));
// => 3oranges, 2apples, 4bananas
```

See the [C# demo](https://rextester.com/QWBGK88734) and the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5cd%7b1%2c4%7do%28%3f%3aranges%3f%29%3f%29%3f%28%5cd%7b1%2c4%7da%28%3f%3apples%3f%29%3f%29%3f%28%5cd%7b1%2c4%7db%28%3f%3aananas%3f%29%3f%29%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=3oranges2apples4bananas%0d%0a1orange1apple1banana%0d%0a1o1a1b&o=m).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d{1,4}o(?:ranges?)?)?` - Group 1 (optional): 1 to 4 digits and then `orange` followed with an optional `s` letter or `o`
- `(\d{1,4}a(?:pples?)?)?` - Group 2 (optional): 1 to 4 digits and then `apple` followed with an optional `s` letter or `a`
- `(\d{1,4}b(?:ananas?)?)?` - Group 3 (optional): 1 to 4 digits and then `banana` followed with an optional `s` letter or `b`
- `$` - end of string.

With `ms.Groups.Cast<Group>().Select(y => y.Value).Skip(1)`, we get rid of the whole match in the results, and only get the captured substrings.

**NOTE** If your `apples` or `oranges` can be alternations of non-similar words you may use alternation as well:

```
@"^(\d{1,4}(?:oranges?|tangerines?))?(\d{1,4}(?:apples?|pears?))?(\d{1,4}(?:bananas?|peach(?:es)?))?$"
```